# Not able to connect using Windows Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote, connection, windows

[image]I'm trying to connect pi using Remote Desktop Connection in windows via Ethernet. But it's not detecting. Also in network connection center ethernet is connected but showing as unidentified network. Previously I was able to connect.**Pi has a static IP**.
I tried to scan the IPs using Advanced IP Scanner but no IP was showing related to raspberry pi. The **static IP** set is `192.168.137.55`. I can see this in Pi's network settings(connected to my TV via HDMI).
`ipconfig` screenshot is given below.

Comment: What is the IP of the computer you're connecting from? What is the subnet mask on both devices?

Comment: @stevieb Please see the updated question. I have added a screenshot of ipconfig command in command prompt.

Comment: The RPi and the PC need to be in the same network, which they are not. The computer is in the `192.168.225.0/24` network, and the Pi is in the `192.168.137.0/24` network. You need to change the IP address of the Pi to be in `192.168.225.0/24` (example: `192.168.225.10` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: Okay. Let me try this. Will update soon. Thank you.

Comment: Keep us posted. If it works, I'll make my comment an answer.

Comment: in case you need a CIDR calculator: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php

Comment: @stevieb I worked. Also I tired to change laptop IP first . It worked!!..Thank you.

Comment: Great! I've made it an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RPi and the PC need to be in the same logical network, which they are not.

The computer is in the `192.168.225.0/24` network, and the Pi is in the `192.168.137.0/24` network.

You need to change the IP address of the Pi to be in `192.168.225.0/24` (example: `192.168.225.10` with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`).

Comment: Network engineer here so I may be being abrupt, so if further clarification is desired, let me know and I'll happily update the answer.

Comment: Is it safe changing laptops's IP? Or anything else I should concern about?

Comment: @ShyamMohan If you change your laptop's IP address and it is currently on a network with a gateway/router, then you will no longer be able to A) connect to other devices and B) no longer be able to connect to the Internet. If these devices are simply directly connected, then there's no issue. Just remember that all devices in the network need to be in the same subnet (even your gateway/router that connects to your Internet Service Provider).